# Java Task ProgressProperty error?

Tags: java, task, progress

I have a few Tasks and their progressProperty is -1 at all time. From my experience -1 normally means something, but I could not find anything about it in the documentation. Does anyone know what this means? or is it just an error with how I set the progress?

To bring this Question more to my personal problem you have to know I combine the progressProperty of multiple tasks and bind this to the progress bar with a doubleBinding. As requested, here is some Code, to minimize it, I removed stuff, like the import declarations, the main method and marked important parts.

```
public class X extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private Task<Void> taskRun;
    private Y y;
    private ExecutorService exec; // <-- Executor Service
    private Stage dialog;
    private Stage window;
    //Interface inter;
    Scene scene;

    private ProgressBar progress; // <-- Progress Bar

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        y = new Y();

        window = primaryStage;
        exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); // <-- Executor Service

        progress = new ProgressBar(0.0); // <-- Progress Bar
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().add(progress);
        scene = new Scene(vb);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        run();
    }

    private DoubleBinding progressBinding = null; // <-- Double binding

    private void run() {
            taskRun = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ConverterManager();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(X.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }
            };
            // I need to use the progressProperty of this task first
            progressBinding = taskRun.progressProperty().multiply(1);
            // Binding doubleBinding to progressBar
            progress.progressProperty().bind(progressBinding); 
            exec.execute(taskRun);
    }

    private void ConverterManager() throws InterruptedException {

        progressBinding = null; // <-- Reset doubleBinding

        int anz = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < anz; i++) {
            Task<Void> mt = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // I use another class and have to update
                        // progress there, I do so with a BiConsumer
                        y.setProgressUpdate(this::updateProgress);
                        // Here I call a Method from the other class
                        // the String parameter is, because I use 
                        // a reflection there
                        y.startZ("Z"); 
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(X.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }
            };
            // Here I combine the progress of the different ProgressProperties
            // Also, I notized that mt.ProgressProperty.get() is -1 for all tasks
            DoubleBinding scaledProgress = mt.progressProperty().divide(anz);
            if (progressBinding == null) {
                progressBinding = scaledProgress;
            } else {
                // Adding the scaled down progress of the Task to the 
                // doubleBinding that is connected to the progressBar
                progressBinding = progressBinding.add(scaledProgress);
            }

            exec.execute(mt);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

}
```

Here is the Class Y

```
public class Y {
    private BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> progressUpdate;

    public void setProgressUpdate(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> progressUpdate) {
        this.progressUpdate = progressUpdate;
    }

    void startZ(String className) throws Exception {
        Class cls = Class.forName("stackoverflow." + className);
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();

        Class[] noParams = new Class[0];

        Class[] progressParams = new Class[1];
        progressParams[0] = BiConsumer.class;

        Method bindProgress = cls.getDeclaredMethod("setProgressUpdate", progressParams);
        bindProgress.invoke(obj, progressUpdate);

        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("start", noParams);
        method.invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

And here is the class Z:

```
public class Z
{
    private BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> progressUpdate;

    public void setProgressUpdate(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> progressUpdate) {
        this.progressUpdate = progressUpdate ;
    }

    public void start() {
            int gesamt = 1000;
            for (int i = 1; i < gesamt; i++) {
                if (progressUpdate != null)
                    progressUpdate.accept(i, gesamt);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#getProgress--)

> A value of -1 means that the current progress cannot be determined
>   (that is, it is indeterminate). This property may or may not change
>   from its default value of -1 depending on the specific Worker
>   implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For `Progress Bar` and `Progress Indicator` :

- *A positive value of the progress variable between 0 and 1 indicates the percentage of progress*
- ***A negative value*** for this variable indicates that the progress is in the **indeterminate mode**

---

This will give you like the first row example (values used : `{-1.0f, 0f, 0.6f, 1.0f}`) :

[image]

[*Java Doc - user-interface-tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/progress.htm#JFXUI310)

Comment: Is this because I bind my progressBar to my task befor I set the progressProperty? if not, how could I change that?

Comment: In which way did you bind it ? Edit your post and share some code, without nohelp can be provided